# TypeScript compiler cannot find typings when using inherited tsconfig

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I am doubting that tsconfig.json **inheritance** works as fully as it should. And that "typeRoots" setting is not inherited properly or at all.

http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html

(folder structure below)

```
web.site -> tsconfig.json
- typings
- node_modules
- scripts
  - ts
  - tests
    - ts -> tsconfig.json (this tsconfig extends/inherits web.site - see contents below)
```

If I run tsc command in my web.site folder, it finds typings and compiles sucessfully. Presumably because it uses the **typeRoots** setting correctly.

If I run tsc command in my tests folder, it can't find any typings and fails to compile. You can assume the errors are simply failure to find references to declarations it should find in "typings" folder.

I can copy the same file from tests (which fails) to the root web.site and it then compiles successfully.

Clearly, it is not using the tsconfig.json properly because given the inheritance, I've setup, it should find typings via the inherited **typeRoots** settings. But is not.

Should I just ignore inheritance as something half-baked and use separate tsconfigs for this?

in web.site/tsconfig.json:

```
{
"compileOnSave": true,
"compilerOptions": {
    "listFiles": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "classic",
    "outDir": "scripts/js",
    "typeRoots": [
        "node_modules/@types",
        "typings"
    ]
},
"include":[
    "scripts/ts/**/*"
]
```

}

in tests/tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "js",
        "removeComments": false
    },
        "include": [
        "ts/**/*"
    ]
}
```

Comment: What if you add `typeRoots` to the inner `tsconfig.json` with `../..` prefixed to the paths?

Comment: @cartant  I confirm, this works. But proves there's a bug in the inheritance? The doco says the path should be relative to the originating file.

Comment: I dunno. Perhaps. Which file is the originating file? There's some ambiguity there. I've used `extends`, but my use case was pretty simple and I don't remember reading the docs in detail.

Comment: @cartant originating file should just mean the one it's in - ie this should work

Comment: Yeah, you are right. It does look buggy.

Comment: I've had a quick look at the TypeScript GitHub issues and couldn't find one (open or closed) that relates to this problem. Perhaps you could [open one](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues)?

Comment: Thanks @cartant I will do soon

Answer (score 2):

There are two parts to this issue:

1. Understanding which properties can be inherited, and which can't

   Although I haven't found any official documentation, there was some discussion in the original [Configuration Inheritance](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9876) proposal regarding which properties could be inherited and which would have to be in the leaf configuration file.

   From my experimentation I have found that some path-based properties, such as `baseUrl` and `paths`, cannot be inherited. I haven't tried using `typeRoots` so I can't say for sure, but it may not be supported by design.
2. Understanding how relative paths are resolved

   When resolving a path, TypeScript will use the location of the leaf configuration file, which it calls the "originating file", as the current working directory for resolving relative paths.

   In the example you mentioned, there is no way to successfully configure the inherited `typeRoots`, since when using `web.site/tsconfig.json` the `node_modules` are in a sibling folder, whereas when using `tests/tsconfig.json` the `node_modules` are in an ancestor folder above.